# Правильный способ хранения текста и HTML-кода в базе MySQL

Tags: php, символы, html, mysql

Каким образом необходимо обрабатывать текст и html-код для записи в базу MySQL? Какая схема?

Перерыл интернет, везде совет для записи в базу использовать mysql_real_escape_string(), и больше вроде ничего не нужно.
Но как быть со спец-мисволами html? К примеру "⇔" при вставке в форму отображается как символ, а не как html-код сивола. Соответственно при записи в базу, он превращается в "?"

Как я понимаю необходимо обрабатывать текст вот так перед вставкой:

```
$inputText = htmlentities($inputText, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$inputText = mysql_real_escape_string($inputText);
```

Соответственно при выводе из базы на отображение необходимо обрабатывать текст вот так:

```
$inputTex = html_entity_decode($inputTex);
```

Такой алгоритм правильный или надо делать как-то по-другому?

Кодировка сайта utf8.

Comment: Я храню только текст в БД. Html храню в шаблонах сайта и рендерю их, подставляя переменные, в которых храниться текст (из БД). А про то, что html нужно хранить в БД слышу впервые. Попробуйте хранить в виде хеша (а как вы собираетесь переносить структуру html с их отступами?).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Вопрос очень простой, но в то же время очень характерный.

В нем отлично собраны наиболее популярные заблуждения начинающих пользователей РНР. Попробуем в них разобраться.

### Хранение

Самое первое, что надо научиться - это не путать *хранение* данных и их *использование в SQL запросах*. Это совершенно разные вещи. По поводу хранения следует понимать, что храниться в БД могут абсолютно *любые* данные, и при этом храниться они должны *как есть*. То есть, для *хранения* их никак, *вообще никак* обрабатывать не нужно.

Следовательно, отвечая на поставленные в посте (не совсем корректные, как мы видим), вопросы:

- Как хранить какие-либо данные в БД? **Данные должны храниться как есть.**
- Как обрабатывать данные для БД? **Никак.** Ни в коем случае никак обрабатывать нельзя.
- Как хранить HTML? Никаких особенных действий ни для HTML, ни для любых других данных производить не нужно. Все данные хранятся абсолютно одинаково.

### Использование данных в SQL запросах.

А вот это уже совсем другой вопрос. Единственный, в ответ на который нам надо будет что-то делать. Но при этом **сами данные** мы всё равно трогать не будем. Да-да! Даже для помещения в SQL запрос мы никак данные обрабатывать не будем. Дело в том, что "совет для записи в базу использовать mysql_real_escape_string()" - это просто феерическая глупость, к сожалению, растиражированная в миллионах экземпляров.

А единственно правильный способ добавления данных в SQL запрос - это делать это через **плейсхолдеры**.

То есть, чтобы использовать любые данные в SQL запросе, надо сначала на их месте написать знаки вопроса:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, lastname) VALUES (?,?)
```

это, кстати, касается **вообще всех запросов.** SELECT мы пишем точно так же:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=?
```

после этого надо будет подготовить запрос, а потом выполнить его, передав переменные **отдельно**. Вот как это происходит на примере PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, lastname) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array($name, $lastame));
```

то есть, идея такая: если нам надо подставить в запрос какую-либо переменную, вместо неё надо поставить знак вопроса. А саму переменную передать после.

Таким образом мы будем гарантированы от любых ошибок и неприятностей, поскольку РНР сам обработает за нас все переменные и сделает это **правильно**.

### Спец-символы HTML

Я думаю, что внимательный читатель уже уловил идею: HTML вообще никакого отношения к БД не имеет. Ни малейшего. Это абсолютно разные вещи. То есть пользователю РНР никогда не должна приходить в голову идея использовать функцию, в которой встречается слово "HTML" для какой-либо работы с БД, а при работе с HTML - функцию, в которой встречается слово "mysql".

Функции для работы с HTML следует применять для работы с HTML.

То есть, если мы собираемся выводить HTML текст в HTML, то мы его должны выводить как есть.

Но если мы собираемся выводить в HTML текст, который не является HTML, мы должны отформатировать его так, чтобы он нам случайно не попортил верстку. Обычно для этого используется функция `htmlspecialchars()`

### Кодировка

Если какой-либо символ сохраняется в виде знака вопроса, то это не проблема HTML кодирования, а проблема кодировки, которая попросту не поддерживает данный символ. Чтобы БД могла сохранять символы типа `⇔`, у нее должна быть кодировка `utf8mb4`. А также РНР скрипт, устанавливая соединение с базой, должен выставлять кодировку этого соединения в `utf8mb4`. При этом отображая пользователю форму, должен выдавать НТТР заголовк `Content-type` с кодировкой `UTF-8`.

И тогда все символы запишутся в целости и сохранности.

Comment: Спасибо, дополню вашим же ответом, чтобы все было в одном месте: [Защита-от-sql-иньекций-в-php](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422113/Защита-от-sql-иньекций-в-php/422165#422165)

Comment: Супер ответ, то что мне было нужно!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86994/discussion-on-answer-by-------html--).

Comment: @Ипатьев Плейсхолдеры не являются единственно правильным способом добавления данных в SQL запрос, а ваше утверждение про mysqli_real_escape_string() - является ошибочным. Эта функция не является устаревшей в документации по PHP, соответственно с вашим утверждением не согласны тысячи человек, принимающих участие в развитии PHP. Использовать mysqli_real_escape_string() можно и нужно для экранирования данных для SQL. Плейсхолдеры будут полезны в первую очередь для новичков, чтобы исключить возможные SQL-инъекции. Просьба не удалять этот комментарий, так как он важен для тех, кто прочитает ответ.

Comment: @Miron, если функция не является устаревшей, это не значит, что её надо использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy - точно так же верно и обратное: если кто-то, не аргументировано считает, что функцию использовать не нужно, то это абсолютно не значит, что её использовать нельзя.

Comment: @Miron если вы считаете, что можете ответить на вопрос лучше / правильнее / более обоснованно - возьмите и ответьте. Приведите в своем ответе конкретный пример, как при использовании плейсхолдеров можно получить sql injection. Уверен, ваш ответ, если он окажется более технически точным и полным, оценят остальные участники.

Comment: И всё же крайне желательно кратко описать в ответе, почему mysqli_real_escape_string это «феерическая глупость», это совершенно неочевидно. Или хотя бы ссылку на документацию, если там это описано.