# Защита от SQL иньекций в php

Tags: php, sql, json, sql-injection

Пишу API, требуется обезопасить его от SQL инъекций. Как лучше и проще защититься от них?

Данные приходят в формате JSON и обрабатываются функцией json_decode(); После чего:

1. Используются в запросах как числа: "... WHERE id='{$id}' ". Требуется функция, которая проверит, что это $id целое число. Или вернет число, к примеру: $id = real_int($id); В результате должно состоять из знака минуса или символов 0-9.
2. Используются как строки: "... '{$text}' ... ".  По идее тут достаточно заменить ' на \', хотя помнится были варианты обхода такой защиты. В общем тоже нужна функция, которая надежно защитит от инъекций.
3. Используются как список идентификаторов: "... WHERE id IN({$ids}) ". Полагаю их проще распарсить и каждый id обработать функцией из первого пункта.

Comment: 1. Используйте хотя бы PDO | 2. Поставьте доктрину и не задумывайтесь о таких вещах вообще.

Comment: [Подготовленные выражения](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php), с IN [повозиться придется](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

Comment: Есть варианты без PDO? В моем случае проще прогнать входящие параметры через функции, чем использовать кучу лишнего кода для работы с PDO.

Comment: Это не лишний код.

Comment: Если без него можно обойтись, он лишний. )

Comment: @mikelsv по этой парадигме php сам по себе лишний

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Разумеется**, вся работа с чистым SQL должна производиться только через плейсхолдеры. Конечно, более предпочтительным вариантом является ORM (идеальный вариант для примитивных запросов, нужных автору) либо прочие квери билдеры - в этом случае пользователь РНР не видит SQL совсем, и следовательно, инъекцию при всем желании устроить не может. Но поскольку новичков эти слова обычно пугают до смерти, то этот вариант подходит только опытным пользователям. При работе же с чистым SQL, повторюсь, любые данные должны попадать в запрос только через плейсхолдеры.

**Разумеется**, защита от инъекций должна производиться способом, отличным от "мы тут сейчас на жувачку прилепим пару функций, там из гуана и палок сварганим другую, потом наваяем ещё кода - и все полетит!". Защита должна быть единообразной и систематической.

**Разумеется**, слой работы с БД должен быть отделен от слоя работы с прикладными данными, и предоставлять удобные и безопасные методы для работы с БД, чтобы не приходилось в бизнес-логике видеть какие-то непонятные вложенные по 30 раз друг в друга array_map, implode, intval и пр. ORM здесь опять на первом месте, а сырой SQL, по-хорошему, имеет смысл использовать только для сложных запросов. Но даже и для чистого SQL DB-layer обязан предоставлять безопасные методы, основанные на плейсхолдерах.

**Разумеется**, в общем случае, использование PDO - это на самом деле, не лишний код, а сокращение кода. Поскольку PDO - единственный из драйверов mysql в РНР, который является высокоуровневой абстракцией, позволяющей сокращать рутинные операции.

**Разумеется**, "implode(',', $ids) в подготовленных запросах" НИКАК НЕ спасёт ситуацию, а лишь вернёт неверные данные.

Разумеется, все эти прекрасные рассуждения разбиваются о простой случай с `WHERE id IN()`...
Можно, конечно, наваять кода, как предлагается по ссылке в комментариях. Но это, на самом деле, будет профанация. Нам не нужны на самом деле эти плейсхолдеры для каждого значения. Нам нужен способ тупо безопасно поместить массив в запрос, не перемешивая бизнес-логику с логикой защиты от инъекций. Для этого надо просто распространить практику работы с плейсхолдерами на несколько дополнительных типов данных. Этим и должен заниматься DB-layer. поскольку ПДО, увы, не предоставляет нужного функционала, можно воспользоваться другими библиотеками. Такими как [DBSimple](http://dklab.ru/lib/DbSimple/) или [Safemysql](http://phpfaq.ru/safemysql). В обоих случаях мы сможем решить все поставленные выше задачи. Вот, к примеру, для safemysql:

Нужен запрос с `WHERE id=1` с проверкой на int?

```
$name = $db->getOne("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?i", $id);
```

Будет выброшена ошибка, если в $id - не число.

Нужен запрос со строковой переменной?

```
$row = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?s", $email);
```

Переменная $email будет корректно отформатирована, и никакой мусор в ней не приведет к инъекции.

Нужен запрос с пресловутым `WHERE id IN()`? Ради бога - всего лишь указываем нужный тип:

```
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN(?a)", $ids);
```

И опять драйвер сам отформатирует массив так, что инъекция не пройдет. **Но сделает это все незаметно для пользователя.** В этом и состоит смысл программирования - делегировать различные задачи разным сервисам, чтобы каждый занимался своим делом. Чтобы "лишний код" был инкапсулирован в свой сервис, а не писался в одной большой куче, как это принято в похапе.

Нужно добавить в БД строку прямиком из джейсона? Нет проблем.

```
$json = '{"name":"John","lastname":"Doe"}';
$db->query("INSERT INTO table SET ?u", json_decode($json,true));
```

здесь будут правильно отформатированы для запроса не только данные, но и имена полей, про которые обычно вообще не думают, а если и думают, то форматируют все равно неправильно.

Comment: Порекомендую к списку ПО для использования Doctrine. Это *сложный* инструмент, который умеет *всё*. Вплоть до группировки запросов к БД (при сохранении сущностей), вплоть до собственной модификации SQL-диалекта, вплоть до не-обращения к базе данных, если сущность с запрошенным PK уже существует в памяти. Единственный косяк, который мне встретился - ошибка при IN-поиске по Many-To-Many отношению.

Comment: В дополнении к ответу. @mikelsv Преимущества PDO, а вместе с тем, использование подготовленных выражений мной [описаны тут с примерами](http://goo.gl/peXM6J). Кроме того, данные перед запрос необходимо привести к соответствующему типу, а также санитизировать, чтобы избежать [XSS](https://goo.gl/6V1Z1m). В том ответе, я указал две свои библиотеки. Существуют обзоры по ним на хабре: [валидатор](http://habrahabr.ru/post/253621/) и [санитизатор](http://habrahabr.ru/post/254045/).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/639411/179379