# Символы < или > в TextArea не сохраняют в базе весь не текст, только часть

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, extjs

Клиент на ExtJS на сервере PHP и MySQL. Проблема в Textarea. Объект:

```
'field' => 
array (
  'type' => '',
  'unique' => '',
  'db_isNull' => true,
  'required' => false,
  'validator' => '',
  'db_type' => 'longtext',
  'db_default' => false,
  'is_search' => false,
  'allow_html' => false,
),
```

При вводе текста с символом **<** и сохранении записывается только то что стоит перед знаком **<**. Изменял `allow_html = true` не помогает. Кто что может подсказать?

Comment: Как у вас организовано сохранение данных в бд? Почитайте вот этот ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422165/186083 на другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score -1):

Перед запросом на добавление данных, оберните их через `mysql_real_escape_string($var)`