# Mysqli запрос ошибка UPDATE

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Хочу изменить `confirm` там где email и id ровны GET-овским данным.
Я новичок в mysqli потому такие ошибки и сотворяю.
Вот код:

```
$quer = "UPDATE `users` SET `confirm` = '1' WHERE `users`.`email` = 
'$_GET[eml]', `users`.`id` = '$_GET[num]'";
$db->query($quer);
```

Comment: В условиях отбора запятая не по делу. Замените её логическим оператором AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `users` SET `confirm` = '1' WHERE `email` = ? AND `id` = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $_GET['eml'], $_GET['num']);    
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->errno) {
  // обработка ошибки
}

echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";

$stmt->close();
```

- [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) — Подготавливает SQL выражение к выполнению
- [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) — Привязка переменных к параметрам подготавливаемого запроса
- [Что такое подготовленные выражения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
- [Грамотная защита от SQL-Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/393450/191482)
- [Защита от SQL иньекций в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422165/191482)
- [Защищают ли подготовленные выражения/переменные полностью от SQL инъекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/191482)

Answer (score 0):

`users`.`id` = '$_GET[num]'"; у вас наверно число integer, уберите скобки чтоб вышло так`users`.`id` = $_GET[num]";

Comment: если вы пишете число в числовое поле, то в MySQL использовать кавычки не нужно, а вообще советую выгружать запрос с помощью file_put_contents('имя_файла.txt', $quer) и выполнять его через СУБД, например очень удобная штука для новичком -> HeidiSQL