# проблема с селектом syntax error, unexpected '$r' (T_VARIABLE) in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

привет всем, у меня такая проблема 
при выполнении etogo

```
$posts4 = null;
if($_POST['hero']) {
    //var_dump($r);
    $r = $_POST['hero4'];
    $query = ' SELECT * FROM apranq_test  WHERE type = "մոտորներ" AND param_2 = '$r' ' ; 
    //var_dump($query);
    $select_op = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $posts3 = mysqli_fetch_all($select_op, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $posts4 = array_reverse($posts3);
    //print_r($posts3);
    //echo $posts3;
},
```

кода пишет syntax error, unexpected '$r' (T_VARIABLE) in 24 
не мог найти проблему

Comment: проблема здесь → `AND param_2 = '$r' '`

Comment: я писал вместо $r конкретную инфу, все работало,

Comment: _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в запрос, пользуйтесь связываемыми переменными http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @RafaelKazaryan взгляни внимательно на строку...

Comment: нехватает запятой?

Comment: Почему запятой? ты же конкатинировать хотел, не?

Comment: я просто новичек,не понимаю многого

Comment: я хотел вставит переменную

Answer (score 2):

- Вставлять переменную в строку можно только если строка обрамлена двойными кавычками. В одинарных если написать `echo '$r'` то и выведется `$r`. Поэтому единственный вариант вставить переменную в строку с одинарными кавычками:  закрыть строку кавычкой, **сконкатинировать переменную**, открыть строку кавычкой и добавить остальную часть не забыв закрыть снова.

  Разница в строках: **http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php**

  Примеры:

  ```
  $myVar = 'Hello world!';

  // строка с одинарными кавычками
  $singleQuoteString = 'Привет мир по английски: '. $myVar .' Вот так!';
  // строка с двойными кавычками
  $doubleQuoteString = "Привет мир по английски: $myVar Вот так!";
  // строка с двойными кавычками2 - для сложных переменных
  $doubleQuoteString = "Привет мир по английски: {$myVar} Вот так!";
  ```
- Если строка обрамлена в одинарные кавычки, то чтобы внутри описать еще кавычки — надо писать либо двойные `"`, либо экранировать одинарные `\'`

  ```
  $myVar = 'Hello world!';        

  // строка с одинарными кавычками
  $singleQuoteString = 'Я печатаю строку "'. $myVar .'"';
  // строка с одинарными кавычками 2 (трудночитаемый вариант)
  $doubleQuoteString = 'Я печатаю строку \''. $myVar .'\'';
  ```
- Двойных кавычек касается то же правило, что одинарные, только наоборот

  ```
  $myVar = 'Hello world!';        

  // строка с двойными кавычками
  $doubleQuoteString = "Я печатаю строку '$myVar'";
  // строка с двойными кавычками 2 (трудночитаемый вариант)
  $doubleQuoteString = "Я печатаю строку \"$myVar\"";
  ```
- Чтобы не мучиться с подстановкой переменных в строку запроса (и не только поэтому) - следует использовать подготовленные запросы: **http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php** | **[Защита от SQL иньекций в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422165/191482)**

Comment: примеров бы добавить.

Comment: @rjhdby добавил. надеюсь верно)

Comment: @RafaelKazaryan добавил примеров. думаю поймешь что и где нужно поправить

Answer (score 0):

Вот так нехватает конкатинации и экранирования.

```
$query = ' SELECT * FROM apranq_test  WHERE type = "մոտորներ" AND param_2 = \'' . $r . '\'';
```

Но так лучше не делать как уже писали http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: сейчац попробую оба варианта

Answer (score 0):

А так?

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM apranq_test  WHERE type = 'մոտորներ' AND param_2 = '$r' ";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $query = " SELECT * FROM apranq_test  WHERE type = 'մոտորներ' AND param_2 = '".$date."' " ;
```