# Можно ли в этом скрипте провести sql инъекцию?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Можно ли в этом скрипте провести sql инъекцию ?

```
$logirovka = $_COOKIE["Login"]; 
$pass = $_COOKIE["Pass"];

$summa=$_POST[ik_am];

$key=time();

$mysqli = new mysqli("***", "***","***","**");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `eg` (`id`, `summa`, `key`, `user`) VALUES (NULL, '$summa', '$key', ' $logirovka');");
```

Comment: можно. вопрос можно закрывать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Спасибо за ответ. Можно закрывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краткий ответ уже дал Алексей: да, код уязвим.

Более подробно.

У вас три вектора атаки. Вы берёте две переменные из массива входных параметров - из $_COOKIE и из $_POST, эти данные передаются с клиентской стороны браузером.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ведь никто не запрещает сделать вам запрос не из браузера, а, скажем из curl, верно? Выставить любые значения в куки и пост, попробовать провести иньекцию.

Без знания вашего кода это будет слепая sql-инъекция, но разницы особой нет: существует масса средств, которые это делают автоматизированно. Мне например, приходится ежеквартально проходить аудит десятка сайтов и я постоянно получаю как PoC, так и конкретные примеры.

Образцы Sql-иньъекций можно посмотреть даже в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0): закрыть кавычку, написать свой код, закрыть обратно кавычку.

Поэтому никогда не пишите такой код, как вы привели: обязательно используйте плейсхолдеры!

PS Старая статья 2012 года, не потерявшая актуальности: [Защита от SQL-инъекций в PHP и MySQL](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148701/)

Comment: да у нас тоже что-то имеется по этому поводу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20  .....  Николай старался https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/191482 .... в ответе на мой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/191482  - тоже есть некий итоге........... хотел предложить [ответы Ипатьева](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422165/191482).. но что-то там как-то немного сумбурно для новичков он пишет

Comment: Собственно благодарю. Я это по сути не для себя, заказчик скинул этот скрипт, но до последнего не верил, что прошлый кодер ему мог написать уязвимый скрипт. Задал вопрос что бы пруфануть.