# SQL Инъекция без GET параметров

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Возможны ли SQL инъекции если на сайте не используются GET параметры ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637185/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-sql-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно. Через POST параметры также можно передать что угодно.

И вообще, инъекции могут быть в любых данных, поступающих от пользователя. В том числе в массивах `$_COOKIE`, `$_SERVER`, `$_FILES`

Comment: И через COOKIE тоже, буквально на днях [спрашивали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749165/213987).

Comment: @AK Расширил ответ