# Как получить элемент json?

Tags: php, json

Хочу получить элемент json — `block_reward`.

```
array (
  'coins' => 
  array (
    'Decred' => 
    array (
      'id' => 152,
      'tag' => 'DCR',
      'algorithm' => 'Blake (14r)',
      'block_time' => '313.0',
      'block_reward' => 6.783715451436188,
      'block_reward24' => 6.783715451436157,
      'last_block' => 628353,
```

Как это правильно сделать?

вот функция

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testphp (name, gender, designation)
 VALUES('".$row['coins']['Decred']
['block_reward']."','".$row["tag"]."','".$row["algorithm"]."')";
```

В таблице почему-то выводятся пустые строки.

Comment: а в БД какие типы у полей? судя по запросу ты вообще не туда всё пихаешь.. сравни "name, gender, designation" и "block_reward, tag, algorithm" ....это вообще как?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в бд все типы полей int "сравни "name, gender, designation" и "block_reward, tag, algorithm" ....это вообще как?" Это я не понял. я передаю значения в колонки под названием name, gender, designation. Какая разница с block_reward, tag, algorithm, там же числа передаются

Comment: в том числе и name? и gender?  ...ну вот смотри... все поля int, а ты вставляешь какой тип?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, всё поля int. я передаю varchar через values . А как мне поменять на int?))

Comment: Если ты просто пробуешь конструкции языка и изучаешь язык, то просто попробуй воткнуть целое число не из массива а просто так.......в ином случае тут всё неправильно и всё не так и лучше так не писать никогда

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, напишите, если не сложно, пожалуйста, функцию, которая смогла бы работать, или там много? (без втыкания просто числа просто так)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно и самые простые варианты, тоже будет полезно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218197/191482  ... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422165/191482  ...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это можно сделать через php pdo?

Comment: mysqli или pdo...